# How to check the current values of variables while debugging an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

I am unable to view the values of variables while running an SSIS package.
I tried to set break point on the data flow tab but after the break point is hit , i am unable to trace the value of variables. Is it displayed in a different window?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the watch window.  This confused me in the past as well.